# Installation of midaspy packages

Tags: python, installation, package, anaconda, spyder

How do I import packages not on pypi with pip?

I am having trouble importing the package "[midaspy](https://github.com/Yoseph-Zuskin/midaspy/tree/master)" to my spider ide. Even though i used pip install and i can see the packages in the anaconda environment, it still cannot be imported in the ide console. I am new to python and used to R.

I get the error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'midaspy' when trying to import it. Hope someone can help.

I tried pip install.
Then pip uninstall (which did not work)

and then conda install -c conda-forge midaspy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the command I used to get the package:

`pip install git+https://github.com/Yoseph-Zuskin/midaspy.git@master#egg=midaspy`

example imports:

```
from midaspy.iolib import *
from midaspy.model import MIDASRegressor
```

This is the guide for importing packages from git: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-vcs

Comment: yes i tried pip install midaspy. And the midaspy shows up in the anaconda navigator environment. But it does not work when i try to import it.

I terms of requirements I think I have just updated all my packages.

My python version is : Python 3.9.16 (main, Mar  8 2023, 10:39:24) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 8.10.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

Comment: Users of MIDASpy must have TensorFlow installed as a pip package in their Python environment. MIDASpy is compatible with both TensorFlow 1.X and TensorFlow >= 2.2 versions.

Once these packages are installed, users can import the dependencies and load the data.
Do you have tensorflow?

Comment: Yes, but i downloaded tensorflow using anaconda, where midaspy is not available in anaconda. I don't know if this matters

Comment: I am not sure but i would try uninstalling all anaconda packages and reinstalling through pip, since midas is unavailable through anaconda. LMK if you keep having more problems. Also can you copy the output of `pip freeze` from your terminal

Comment: I just noticed that i am referring to midaspy, which is different from MIDASpy. This is the packages i want: https://github.com/Yoseph-Zuskin/midaspy

Comment: I updated the answer with the command that worked for me